# C++ how to get output into a file

Tags: c++, c++11

So I am not sure how to get the output to like a .txt file, the code keeps giving me a .txt file but it is always empty. I know I am supposed to include a line where it outputs the information but I am uncertain of what to put in the line since its a void function and it doesn't return anything, would changing it to a different type of function solve the problem?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "ArgumentManager.h"

using namespace std;

void permute(string a, int l, int r)
{
  if (l == r)
    cout<<a<<endl;
  else
  {
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
    {
      swap(a[l], a[i]);
      permute(a, l+1, r);
      swap(a[l], a[i]);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ArgumentManager am(argc, argv);
  ifstream input;
  ofstream output;

  string infileName = am.get("input");
  string outfileName = am.get("output");
  input.open(infileName);
  output.open(outfileName);

  string str;

  int n = str.size();
  permute(str, 0, n-1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with infileName or outfileName? Use them accordingly. outfileName << whatever_you_want_to_put_in_output_file.

Comment: `string str; int n = str.size()` ??  What do you think is in the string?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI the infileName and outfileName are being used within the argumentmanager, I had to include those otherwise it won't read the code it needs. The main issue is I know I need to outfileName << whatever, but my concern is that I do not know what I put after outfileName << since the void function isnt returning anything

Comment: I can't tel what you need from the example above. But guessing you want to replace the one cout statement with something like. void permute(string a, int l, int r, ostream& out_file); out_file << a << endl; instead of cout << a << endl;

Comment: Basically the code is supposed to read a .txt with an input in it, run the code and print out all possible combinations(ex: input is mn then the output should be mn and nm but needs to work with any string like abc). Then after it does the code and stuff it needs to output to another .txt file named output.

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked with ArgumentManager before in C++.
But can you use something like:

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I think instead of passing the output to cout, you should pass it to myfile object.

Comment: Writing `myfile.close();` is entirely unnecessary. The file handle is already closed by the destructor.